# Inno Setup: Is there any way to set a registry key value when uninstalling?

Tags: inno-setup

I know how to have Inno Setup create/manipulate registry keys and/or values on install and I know that you can delete a value, a key, etc when uninstalling. But is there any way to have Inno Setup actually change the value of a key when the uninstall process is done?

The setup I'm creating changes the value of a dword key that another application uses to a value to 1, indicating it's installed, and when this application is removed I need the value to be restored to 0, indicating it's removal. Is this possible, without deleting the actual key/value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use specific `RegWrite` function (for `DWord`, `Binary`, `StringValue`, etc) in `procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);` with `usPostUninstall` or `usDone`

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
    RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\My Company\My Program',
      'UserName', ExpandConstant('{sysuserinfoname}'));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works. However it should be noted that RegWriteStringValue is for REG_SZ type values. So in my case I need to use RegWriteDWordValue which is, as the name implies, for DWord values. Put me on the correct path though, so thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem. I have mentioned `DWord`, `Binary`, `String` in introduction. As I didn't know which one you need, I gave an example with `String`.